# Sales Tax Exempt Extension for Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3.4

i have searched Sales Tax Exempt extension for Magento 2.3,

[i have found for Magento 1.9,](https://www.emjainteractive.com/magento-sales-tax-exempt-orders-checkout-option.html)

but the same extension I want for Magento 2,
is there available the same for Magento 2 or any other extension like Magento 1?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this module for Magento 2.

https://technology.pillwax.com/software/magento-extensions/euvat-for-magento.html